# Mouse hover action is not working in selenium webdriver for demo website

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have tried the below code.

```
public class FindingMultipleElements {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.navigate().to("http://automationpractice.com/index.php");
        Actions act = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement women = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='block_top_menu']/ul/li[1]/a"));
        //women.click();
        Point p1 = women.getLocation();
        int x = p1.getX();
        int y = p1.getY();
        System.out.println("X:"+x+" Y:"+y);
        act.moveByOffset(x, y).click(driver.findElement(By.linkText("T-shirts"))).build().perform();

    }
}
```

[image]

I need to click the "T-shirts" link inside the women category. Not able to click the link by using Mouse hover Actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the below code :

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.navigate().to("http://automationpractice.com/index.php");
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

WebElement women = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul>li:nth-child(1)>a[title='Women']"));

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);  
builder.moveToElement(women).perform();//this will hover to women
Thread.sleep(1000);//avoid using this type of wait. wait using until.

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul>li:nth-child(1)>a[title='T-shirts']")).click();//this will click on t-shirt
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: Working fine Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are already providing `X` and `Y` coordinates then why providing `driver.findElement(By.linkText("T-shirts"))` also ? Try without that and it would work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no element By.linkText("T-shirts")

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
WebElement womenLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Women']"));
act.moveToElement(womenLink).click().build().perform();
WebElement tshirtLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@class='sfHoverForce']//a[@title='T-shirts']"));
act.moveToElement(tshirtLink).click().build().perform();
```